# How to split text array?

Tags: python, django

I have array of answers including marks.

> Syntax - ["ANSWER1|MARK1, ANSWER2|MARK2 ...]

```
answers = ["Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications|3",
             "A survey of user opinion of computer system response time|4",
             "The EPS user interface management system|2",
             "System and human system engineering testing of EPS|1"]
```

I need to split these and extract marks for each answer. How do i do it ?

Comment: Here are some pointers to the documentation. You're working with strings, so a first stop would be the [string methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), in particular the `split` method. You're also working with a list, so see the [`for` statement](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) and/or [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
>>> [a.split("|") for a in answers]
[['Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications', '3'], 
['A survey of user opinion of computer system response time', '4'], 
['The EPS user interface management system', '2'], 
['System and human system engineering testing of EPS', '1']]
```

Comment: Just ["Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications", ... ]

Comment: @ChamingaD if this answer has solved your problem, you can select it as your accepted answer